# documentation for C++ API for node v0.12

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

Is there a full documentation about C++ API for node.js?

Everything that I was able to find is http://izs.me/v8-docs/main.html which seems to be quite old. And based on this article https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-v0-12-c-apis-breaking/ there are serious changes in API for node v0.12.

The problem is that I need to migrate old module to 0.12 and it is almost impossible without documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, in node.js documentation:

https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

And you'll find everything you want to know about v8 at developers.google.com/v8:

https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started